# Android: Add my WebView Activity to the Chooser Web Browser

Tags: android, webview

I have an app has (1 XML and 1 activity):

1. An edit text to fill in the url.
2. A button to open web browser.
   [My home screen app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNaRP.png)

My activity:

```
public class ActivityBai2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnMoTrinhDuyet;
private EditText editTextLink;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bai2);

    btnMoTrinhDuyet = findViewById(R.id.buttonMoTrinhDuyet);
    editTextLink = findViewById(R.id.editLink);

    btnMoTrinhDuyet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url = editTextLink.getText().toString();
            if(!url.equals("")) {
                if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
                    url = "http://" + url;
                }
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityBai2.this, "Vui lòng nhập địa chỉ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

I created 1 XML that contains a WebView (and 1 activity to show WebView).

```
public class ActivityBai3 extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bai3);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Uri data = i.getData();
    URL url = null;

    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    try {
        url = new URL(data.getScheme(), data.getHost(), data.getPath());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myWebView.loadUrl(url.toString());

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });


}
```

}

How can I add this webview into The Chooser Web Browser Window when clicked The button.

Here the first XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nhập đường link trang web"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editLink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMoTrinhDuyet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="mở trình duyệt"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks you!

I add this to AndroidManifest.xml and it work.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityBai2" android:label="home screen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityBai3" android:label="My Web Browser">
        <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow other apps to access your activity you must add intent filter to your activity.

[Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Comment: Thanks for the keyword!